# How to represent a negative number with a fraction in 2's complement?

Tags: twos-complement

So I want to represent the number `-12.5`. So 12.5 equals to:

```
001100.100
```

If I don't calculate the fraction then it's simple, `-12` is:

```
110100
```

But what is -12.5? is it `110100.100`? How can I calculate this negative fraction?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With decimal number systems, each number position (or column) represents (reading a number from right to left): units (which is 10^0), tens (i.e. 10^1),hundreds (i.e. 10^2), etc.

With unsigned binary numbers, the base is 2, thus each position becomes (again, reading from right to left): 1 (i.e. 2^0) ,2 (i.e. 2^1), 4 (i.e. 2^2), etc.

**For example**

```
2^2 (4), 2^1 (2), 2^0 (1).
```

In signed twos-complement the most significant bit (MSB) becomes negative. Therefore it represent the number sign: '1' for a negative number and '0' for a positive number.

For a three bit number the rows would hold these values:

```
-4, 2, 1
 0  0  1 => 1
 1  0  0 => -4
 1  0  1 => -4 + 1 = -3
```

The value of the bits held by a fixed-point (fractional) system is unchanged. Column values follow the same pattern as before, base (2) to a power, but with power going negative:

```
2^2 (4), 2^1 (2), 2^0 (1) . 2^-1 (0.5), 2^-2 (0.25), 2^-3 (0.125)
```

-1 will always be `111.000`
-0.5 add 0.5 to it: `111.100`

In your case `110100.10` is equal to -32+16+4+0.5 = -11.5. What you did was create -12 then add 0.5 rather than subtract 0.5.

What you actually want is -32+16+2+1+0.5 = -12.5 = `110011.1`

Comment: to complete the answer:
you add 0.5 to subtract 0.5 because you add a positive value to a negative value, so:
-0.25  add (1-0.25=0.75) to it: 111.11

Answer (score 6):

So;U want to represent -12.5 in 2's complement representation

> 12.5:->> 01100.1
>
> 2's complement of (01100.1):->>10011.1

verify the ans by checking the weighted code property of 2's complement representation(MSB weight is -ve). we will get -16+3+.5=-12.5

Answer (score 5):

you can double the number again and again until it's negative integer or reaches a defined limit and then set the decimal point correspondingly.

-25 is 11100111, so -12.5 is 1110011.1